# Why I am getting wrong answer?

Tags: java

I am new to java.. when i run this program i am getting this result

**value of a in class A is 2

value of k in class B is 6

value of a in class B is 0

sum is 6**
why i am getting value of a is 0 in class B ?

```
class A{
    int a;
    void showa(){
        System.out.println("value of a in class A is "+a);
    }
}
class B extends A{
    int k;
    void showk(){
        System.out.println("value of k in class B is "+k);
        System.out.println("value of a in class B is "+a);
    }
    void res(){
        System.out.println("sun is "+(k+a));    
    }
}
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        A a = new A();
        a.a=2;
        B b = new B();
        b.k =6;
        a.showa();
        b.showk();
        b.res();
    }
}
```

Comment: What value are you expecting? Since it's not assigned it has its default value, 0.

Comment: b and a are separate instances, so their a's have a different value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `B` instance `b`, you never set the value of `a`, so Java gave it the default value of 0.

- [The Java tutorial on default values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (scroll down on that page to the "Default Values" section)

Answer (score 3):

B extends A, but the 2 objects are not the same. A has a=2, B has a=0 k=6. when you call res, you add the values in B. If you do this:

```
B b = new B();
b.a = 2;    
b.k =6;
```

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are class (`static`) attributes and object attributes. You declared object attributes. As such, your code boils down to

```
a.a = 2;
b.k = 6;
println(b.a + b.k);
```

The problem is that you never set `b.a`.

Fix 1:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    b.a = 2;
    b.k = 6;
    b.showa();
    b.showk();
    b.res();
}
```

Fix 2:

```
static int a;   // Instead of int a;
static int k;   // Instead of int k;
```

Which one is correct? Probably the first one, but one can't tell without knowing the purposes of the classes and attribute.

Answer (score 0):

because `a` and `b` are different Java objects.
i.e., you created a `B` instance `b`, that extends from `A` class, not from `a` instance.
you only made the set on instance `a`

Answer (score 0):

b.a has not been initialised and so has value zero.
you would need `b.a = 2` statement.